# Windows 10 Kerberos error when calling SharePoint library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-10, kerberos

I have an old Windows Forms application which was written for .NET 2.0. One of the processing steps calls a SharePoint 2007 web service. The application runs on a Windows 7 machine but fails to connect to SharePoint with a Kerberos error (KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN) when run on a Windows 10 machine. I have not jumped into Win 10 C# development yet, so this difference in the environments is escaping me. Any suggestions on correcting this issue?

Details:

- C# project contains a web reference to the custom SharePoint web service
- Code snippet:

  WebReference.Lists listService = new WebReference.Lists();

  listService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserID, Password, Domain);

  XmlNode ndReturn = listService.UpdateListItems(listName, xmlElement);

Comment: Don't look for obscure Windows 10 incompatibilites.  SharePoint is a server product, just like SQL Server. If you have issues, you can't fix them with code. You have to find and solve the actual *system* issue. In this case you probably use a machine that isn't on the same domain as SharePoint, or you are running your code with a local instead of a domain account.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are on a Windows 2003 domain you may have run into incompatibilities indeed. Windows 2003 is *very* old - so old that the relevant articles have been [retired from Technet]((http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2064.kerberos-error-code-0x7-kdc-err-s-principal-unknown-dsforum2wiki.aspx), including the one about [troubleshooting this Kerberos error](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53314). You can download the entire bundle and look for the article there. In any case, this is a system error that you just can't fix with code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you capture the DNS and Kerberos traffic on the client (ports 88 and 53, TCP and UDP) with Wireshark. The error implies that it gets the point of talking to a KDC via Kerberos, so there will be something to look at. Just before running the application do the following to flush cached information: `ipconfig /flushdns` and `klist purge`. Are the client hosts joined to the same domain?